# Permutation code not doing exactly what i want it to do

Tags: python, permutation, combinations

im very new to python and i have done this code that not doing what i want exactly.
Help is appreciated alot.

Here is my code i have so far

```
def permute(LIST):

    length=len(LIST)
    if length <= 1:
        yield LIST
    else:
        for n in range(0,length):
             for end in permute( LIST[:n] + LIST[n+1:] ):
                 yield [ LIST[n] ] + end
```

when i give it something like [4,3,2,1] it doesnt repeat the last number, it only
does combinations for each letter once. So the output will never be [4,3,2,2] for example.

but I want it to do this. here is an example of what i want the output to be like

```
INPUT = ['1','2','3','4']

OUTPUTs = [1 2 3 4][1 2 3 1][1 2 3 2][1 2 3 3] [1 2 4 1][1 2 4 2] [1 2 4 3] [1 2 4 4] [1 2 1 1]and so on
```

what can i do to my code to implement this change?

thank you for your kind help

EDIT: I CANNOT USE ITERTOOLS

Comment: I'm afraid that what you want is not permutation.

Comment: check my answer anyway..

Answer (score 1):

OK. I got -1 for using itertools.permutations :(

Seems like you need permutation with repetition without using itertools.
Here you go:

```
def permutation_with_repitition(items, prefix):
  if len(prefix) == len(items):
     yield prefix

  else:
    for item in items:
      prefix.append(item)
      for p in  permutation_with_repitition(items, prefix):
        yield p
      prefix.pop()

L = [1,2,3]

for p in permutation_with_repitition(L, []):
  print p
```

output:

```
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 3]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 1]
[1, 3, 2]
[1, 3, 3]
[2, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[2, 3, 2]
[2, 3, 3]
[3, 1, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 1, 3]
[3, 2, 1]
[3, 2, 2]
[3, 2, 3]
[3, 3, 1]
[3, 3, 2]
[3, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

But maybe [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) is what you want:

```
>>> I = range(3)
>>> print list(itertools.product(I, repeat=len(I)))
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (2, 0, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 0, 2), (2, 1, 0), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 0), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2)]
```